# How to fill dummy values as a pattern in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like given below

```
op1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
     'date' : ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017','1/4/2017','1/5/2017','1/6/2017'],
     'val' :[5,10,5,16,26,6]
    })
```

This looks like shown below

[image]

I am trying to fill the value `vac` at every record starting from `0th` index with a step value of `2`

```
op1['flag'] = ['vac',start = 0, step = 2]
```

I can use `insert` like below but I have to repeat this multiple times

```
op1.insert(2, "flag", "vac")
```

I expect my output to look like as shown below

[image]

Comment: All the answers below are good. Especially Yatu and Mark's answer had very short condition. Nonetheless other answers also gave expected output. However I can mark only one answer as solution, so I go with Yatu's answer. Thank you everyone for the help. Upvoted all the answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign a new empty column, and fill every `2` positions with `vac`:

```
op1['flag'] = ''
op1.loc[::2, 'flag'] = 'vac'

    subject_id   date    val flag
0           1  1/1/2017    5  vac
1           1  1/2/2017   10     
2           1  1/3/2017    5  vac
3           1  1/4/2017   16     
4           1  1/5/2017   26  vac
5           1  1/6/2017    6
```

Comment: That `::2` assignment is pure genius!

Answer (score 1):

```
op1['flag'] = np.where(op1.index % 2, '', 'vac')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
>>> op1["flag"] = ["vac" if i % 2 == 0 else "" for i in range(len(op1.subject_id))]
>>> op1
       date  subject_id  val flag
0  1/1/2017           1    5  vac
1  1/2/2017           1   10
2  1/3/2017           1    5  vac
3  1/4/2017           1   16
4  1/5/2017           1   26  vac
5  1/6/2017           1    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
op1['New']=(['','val']*((len(op1)//2)+1))[:len(op1)]
```